# How to create a series of DIVs using PHP + mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, divider

I'm looking to create a formatted product list from an SQL database. My aim is to have a store on my website with a series of small boxes containing some shorthand information about each product, that when clicked will open a pop-up containing detailed information. (I have a working Javascript/JQuery code to create the pop-ups.)

Here is the PHP code so far, simply to get the information from the database and display it on a webpage...
(I've been using XAMPP to provide an environment for me to test the code in)

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());

mysql_select_db("Database1") or die(mysql_error());

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Products";

$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

echo $row['Brand'] . " " . $row['ProductName'] . " " . $row['Image'] . "<br />";

}

mysql_close();
?>
```

I want the echoed line to be displayed in a divider, with a divider generated for each record in the SQL database (say I have 10 products available, there would be ten dividers, and 10 different boxes on the webpage). The divider's class is "ProductBox".

```
echo "<div class=\"ProductBox\">"; $row['Brand'] . " " . $row['ProductName'] . " " . $row['Image'] . "</div>";
```

This was the closest I have come to a solution, which was simply managing to write a code with no syntax errors - alas, nothing actually displays on the webpage.

If I'm going about this entirely the wrong way please tell me - I'm fairly sure I need to use a SQL database to dynamically update stock on a live website, but if I need to implement a different programming language or whatever then just tell me what you think would work and help me with a solution.

Comment: obligatory notice: `mysql` is deprecated. please use `mysqli`.

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra semicolon in your code

```
echo "<div class=\"ProductBox\">"; $row['Brand'] . " " . $row['ProductName'] . " " . $row['Image'] . "</div>";
```

Replace with

```
echo "<div class=\"ProductBox\">". $row['Brand'] . " " . $row['ProductName'] . " " . $row['Image'] . "</div>";
```

Comment: I thought it to be strange that the code was not giving me an error message, in spite of it displaying nothing - this has gotten me a lot closer to what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array needs to be used like this (see [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

}
```

or you could just use "mysql_fetch_assoc" instead.

HOWEVER, if you're new to PHP, I HIGHLY RECOMMEND that you get started on the right foot. mysql_query functions are soon to be deprecated. DON'T USE THEM. Most recommend using "PDO" for querying your database. Here's a great tutorial to teach you: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Also, as mentioned, you have an extra semi-colon.

Comment: Very useful article, once I've got everything working I'll definitely implement this newer function - this website will be going live so it's paramount that it is up to date in terms of compatibility.

Answer (score -2):

Dont forget these basics markups :

```
`<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY> put in here your divs
    </BODY>
</HTML>`
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question

Comment: First of all you don't know that he needs html/body tags - it might be an ajax call. Secondly, this doesn't bring him closer to an answer at all.